# Execute classes based on condition in puppet

Tags: puppet

I want to execute some classes only if a specific rpm version is absent.

For example:

```
class base{
  if specified_rpm_absent {
    include base::class1
    include base::class2
  }
  else {
    notify {"Already there":}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is define a [custom fact](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/fact_overview.html) that returns true or false depending on the presence or absence of this RPM and then use it in your conditional logic, i.e.

Fact code:

```
Facter.add(:specified_rpm_absent) do
  setcode do
    # Some Ruby code to return true or false depending on RPM package
    # Facter::Core::Execution.exec() can be used to execute a shell
    # command.
  end
end
```

Puppet 4

```
class base {
  if $facts['specified_rpm_absent'] {
    include base::class1
    include base::class2
  }
  else {
    notify {"Already there":}
  }
}
```

Puppet 3

```
class base {
  if $::specified_rpm_absent {
    include base::class1
    include base::class2
  }
  else {
    notify {"Already there":}
  }
}
```

The OP has argued below that it is better to use a puppet function here, and functions also allow arguments.

The problem is that [Functions execute on the Puppet master. They do not execute on the Puppet agent. Hence they only have access to the commands and data available on the Puppet master host](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html).

If using Masterless Puppet, however, which is not supported by Puppet, functions could be used for this purpose, and this use-case is described in Jussi Heinonen's book Learning Puppet (2015).

I would not recommend this approach for a few reasons:

- It is not supported by Puppet, and therefore there is no guarantee that a future version of Puppet will not make this impossible.
- The code will not be portable. That is, the code can not be shared on the Puppet Forge, and it can not be migrated to a conventional Master/Puppet set up.
- It is not idiomatic and will confuse people who know Puppet, i.e. violates the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Finally, it should be pointed out that there is probably something more fundamentally wrong with a design that involves making decisions based on whether or not an RPM is installed. Why doesn't Puppet already know if the RPM is installed?

Comment: Any other solution that doesn't need custom facts?

Comment: If your requirement is to execute classes only if a specific rpm version is absent, then this would normally be achieved using a custom fact. I can't think of any other way you could do it either.

Comment: @AlexHarey can we pass parameters to external facts?

Comment: No, but if you're in Puppet 4 you can have structured facts - you could have the fact return a lookup table for example. Mind you I suspect there is something more fundamentally wrong if you need to be making decisions based on versions of RPMs installed.

Comment: Bro. I wrote a puppet function. That was much easier. And it accepts arguments too,

Comment: That will not work however. You may not be aware that puppet functions run on the Puppet Master. So your function will actually be returning info about your Puppet Master, rather than the node being configured, which is probably not what you want, and certainly not recommended.

Comment: "Functions execute on the Puppet master. They do not execute on the Puppet agent. Hence they only have access to the commands and data available on the Puppet master host." https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html

Comment: Of course, it is possible that you are doing Masterless Puppet (which is not supported). In that case, you could use a function and I believe it would work. But it means your code could not be migrated later to a Masterful Puppet setup; it would be regarded as bad practice, and it will be confusing to people who know the Puppet language.

Comment: Yes I am doing master less puppet.

Comment: And the RPM contains war files. So i am checking that where they are already deployed or not. If not or some other versions are deployed the I will install the new RPM. This is what is want to do.

Comment: I assume you have a tool that is deploying the RPM files for you. Could you not have that same tool also update external facts (these are just static key/value pairs in a YAML config file on the Puppet node -
 https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#external-facts), and Puppet will now have this data available as facts in its manifests. Perhaps this seems more complicated, but it is certainly more idiomatic, so I would regard it as cleaner.

Comment: Hey can I do variable interpolation in facter variable?
For example `$::package_${name} ~= /1.2.3/`

Comment: You are really asking if Puppet has an eval https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval  and no it doesn't. If you join the Puppet Community Slack there are people, including myself, who would be happy to discuss your more general requirement.